# Displacement modifier breaks mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, displacement

I am trying to add texture to a logo using the Displacement modifier and a Subsurf modifier as is being done in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBgvZEmE8pc) at around 6:30.

[image]

The logo is made from a .svg curve to which I added extrude and depth effects before converting the curve to a mesh.

[image]

When I add the Displace modifier to the mesh, it instantly breaks.

[image]

Applying location and scale and rotation helps fix this but there are still large cuts and crevices in the result:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way that the mesh won't break?

I tried subdividing a few times, but this didn't really help.

[image]

Comment: I personally love the effect in your third image

Comment: @10Replies yeah it's pretty cool, I agree! I did play with animating this effect as well ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your mesh is splitted into Flat parts (Probably because you used an *Edge Split Modifier*).

To combine it and have it not "Break" you can enter edit mode, select all vertices and press <kbd>W</kbd> then *Remove Doubles*.

**Not related to the question:**

I would recommend you remesh your object to get a better toplogy using the *Remesh Modifier*

[image]